# Can we assume the property is true for some n in proof by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, induction, propositional-calculus

When you're doing a proof by induction and you want to show that the property P(n) holds for all natural numbers n, in the induction step you say: Let n be a natural number and assume P(n) is true. I need to prove that P(n+1) is true.
Is this the same as saying: assume there exists a natural n such that P(n) is true. I need to prove that P(n+1) is true

Stated differently:
Is

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} ( P(n) \implies P(n+1))$
The same as

$(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}  
 P(n)) \implies P(n+1)$

Comment: You need the "for all" version. Note that the "there exists" version could be used to prove every integer greater greater than $1$ is prime: (base case) $2$ is prime. (inductive case) There exists an $n$ such that $P(n) \implies P(n+1),$ namely $n=2.$

Comment: I don't think the second statement means anything.  $n$ is a bound variable on the left, so meaningless on the right.

Comment: Ah... on second reading I see what you mean.  .... Yes... I think of you can prove the statement $(\exists n: P(n)) \implies (P(n+1)$ is true where $n$ is the bound variable in the "exist" statement$)$ that is the same  as $\forall n:P(n)\implies P(n+1)$.  But the statement "The existence of an element implies a condition of the element" is not a statement that an element exists at all and is actually a statement about something that *must* occur to any element that does exist so it is not served by an "exist" statement but by a "forall". And if you take saulspatz warning about boundings....

Comment: Okay... yes  "The existence of an element $n$ that does X implies that $n$ does Y" is logically the same as "For all $n$ that do X then $n$ does Y".  But note that is not the same as "There exist an element $n$ that does X and where $n$ does Y".  In the first the existence is not given but speculated. And speculation "if something exists" is meaningless place holder everthing that is speculated is speculated to exist whether it so does or not.  This is the "A living unicorn exists" fallacy. (If a unicorn is alive, then it exists; So a living unicorn exists. So... somewhere there is a unicorn.)

Answer (score 2):

No.  Those are not the same at all.

Suppose you have $P$ that is true of $7,13, 52,53$ and $79$ but nothing else.

To do a proof by induction (which you *can't* because it is *NOT* true).  You need to prove that if it is true for *any* $n$ then it *must* be true for $n+1$.

You *can't* do this because it is true for $n =7$ but it is not true for $n+1 = 8$. (Nor from $n=13, n+1 = 14$ or $n=79, n+1 = 80$).

So $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} ( P(n) \implies P(n+1))$ is false.

But for $n = 52$ we have $P(n)$ is true and we have $P(n+1) = P(53)$ is true.

So $(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}  P(n)) \implies P(n+1)$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

The induction step is
$$\forall n\geq 0 [P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)]$$
If you have proved the induction base $P(0)$ and the induction step, then you can infer that $$\forall n\geq 0[P(n)]$$
The reason is the modus ponens.

Answer (score 0):

When assuming a statement is true for some arbitrary $n$ what you are doing, logically, is actually using an open formula.

To be more precise, open formulae are well-formed formulae in which the variables are not bounded by any  quantificator. So what you are trying to show is that for an arbitrary element $x$ of the universe of dicourse, in this case, $\mathbb{N}$, the formula $P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1)$ holds. Since that formula is true, then you have proven that $\models (P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1))$. There is a theorem of logic that says that whenever you have an open formula $\varphi(x)$ such that $\models \varphi(x)$ where $x$ is the only free variable (this is important) then $\models \forall x \varphi(x)$. This last step is called closure of formula and this theorem is what guarantees that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the formula $P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1)$ holds in the proof by induction.

So to answer your question, no, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}(P(n)\rightarrow P(n+1))$ is not the same as $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}( P(n))\rightarrow P(n+1)$. In the second formula, only $P(n)$ is bounded by some quantificator, thus, this is an open formula. But see that $n$ is both free and bounded, hence, you cannot apply closure to this formula.